# How to poll for GPIO interrupts in python?

Tags: linux, python-2.7, polling, gpio

I need to poll for interrupts on a GPIO pin using python 2.7, and I wonder if there are any native functions or libraries to help me do that?
When searching for anything like this I find a lot about Raspberry Pi, but that is not what I need.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*It will be greate if you post what you already tried so we can help.*

I did it like this

```
while 1:
    events = po.poll(30000)
    if not events:
        print ('TIMEOUT!')
    for fd, flag in events:
        # check what's been done with os.lseek and os.read
```

This code is based on [How do I wait for interrupts in different languages?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3440/how-do-i-wait-for-interrupts-in-different-languages/4754#4754) question.

Whole code was done as a simple game for emebeded system on Raspberry PI and is available [here](https://github.com/janisz/linsw/blob/4209d1d831073c6250fbbca26c8c66426dd53056/Lab_2/docs/memo.py#L74)

Comment: Thank you! This was just what I was looking for!